# Access android audio output

Tags: android, audio

Hi i want to record sound that is currently played in android handset, actually i want to get access to audio played by speaker or headphones.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not via the Android SDK, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean not by SDK? Is there such possibility in NDK?

Comment: @ZZZ: No. You can write your own mobile OS to do it. It is possible that you could accomplish this via your own custom firmware.

Comment: Great, so i need to start work on it now, maybe i finish it before my retirement :)

Comment: @ZZZ have you got some answer or solution to do this?